# How remove last comma in a string using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm working in pl sql block to add double quote and comma for each break line currently my block is this:

```
DECLARE
v_fulltext varchar2(4000):= '                                                          Total   Total   Total Unbalanced Unbalanced       Flex    Nonflex
Journal Entry Source Name    Group ID           Status    Lines Batches Headers    Batches    Headers     Errors     Errors
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Manual                                    90005 Error        10       1       1          3          1          0          0
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       *** TOTALS ***                                         1       1       1          1          1          0          0';
v_full_text_2 varchar2(4000);
v_full_text_quote varchar2(4000);
counter number := 0;
BEGIN
FOR sumaryline IN(SELECT
            regexp_substr(v_fulltext, '[^('
                                || CHR(13)
                                || CHR(10)
                                || ')]+', 1, level) sumaryline
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        regexp_substr(v_fulltext, '[^('
                                || CHR(13)
                                || CHR(10)
                                || ')]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
LOOP
counter := counter +1;
v_full_text_quote := v_full_text_quote||'"'||sumaryline.sumaryline||'",'||chr(10);
END LOOP;
 dbms_output.put_line(v_full_text_quote);
END;
```

The output is this:
[image]

How can I remove comma from the last line?
I have tried using:

```
END LOOP;
v_full_text_quote := rtrim(v_full_text_quote, ',');
```

But it does not work

Kind Regards.
Cesar.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `,` isn't the last character in your string.. you have a line feed and carriage return following it. Try REGEXP_REPLACE, like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(line,','||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'$',CHR(13)||CHR(10))
  FROM (
     /* sample data */
     SELECT 'line 1,'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||
            'line 2,'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||
            'line 3,'||CHR(13)||CHR(10) line
       FROM dual
      )
```

Outputs:

```
line 1,
line 2,
line 3
```

Of course, if you don't want that last CHR(13)||CHR(10) after the comma, then you could also just trim them all with nested RTRIMs:

```
RTRIM(RTRIM(RTRIM(v_full_text_quote,CHR(10)),CHR(13)),',')
```